# Create arrays from an even number of objects within a loop

Tags: javascript, json, express, web-scraping

I'm building a website-scraper for personal purposes with Javascript (Express).

The objective of the script is to scrape some simple text data from external source and eventually output the scraped data as `JSON` objects. 
However, since there will always be an even amount of objects, I'd like to add them into an array as pairs and this is the part where I need some guidance from you guys.

The current output is just a generic JSON object/objects based on the amount of scraped objects (usually between 8-16):

```
{
  name: "John Doe",
  email: "john.doe@john.com,
  status: "active"
},

{
  name: "Jane Doe",
  email: "jane.doe@jane.com,
  status: "inactive"
},


{
  name: "Johnny Walker",
  email: "johnny.walker@walker.com",
  status: "active"
},

{
  name: "Jimmy Glenfiddich",
  email: "jimmy.glenfiddich@glendfiddich.com
  status: "active"
}
```

And the expected output would look something like this:

```
{

"pair-number": 1,

"pair:" [

  {
    name: "John Doe",
    email: "john.doe@john.com,
    status: "active"
  },

  {
    name: "Jane Doe",
    email: "jane.doe@jane.com,
    status: "inactive"
  },
]
},

{

"pair-number": 2,

"pair:" [
  {
    name: "Johnny Walker",
    email: "johnny.walker@walker.com",
    status: "active"
  },

  {
    name: "Jimmy Glenfiddich",
    email: "jimmy.glenfiddich@glendfiddich.com
    status: "active"
  }
]
}
```

Here's my `server.js`

```
var express = require('express');
var request = require('request');
var cheerio = require('cheerio');
var app     = express();

var url = 'http://testurl.com;
var name, email, status;

app.get('/scrape', function(req, res) {

    request(url, function (error, response, html) {

        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {

            var $ = cheerio.load(html);

            data = {"name": name, "email": email, "status": status };       

            $('.scrape-class').filter(function() {

                var that = $(this);

                name = that.find('h5').text();
                email = that.find('.email').text(); 
                status = that.find('dl').children().first().text();

                data.name = name;
                data.email = email;
                data.status = status;

                console.log(data);
            });
        }
    });
});

app.listen(80, function () {
    console.log('Example app listening on port 80!')
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using modulo (%), to get remainder of a division operation to figure out if your current iteration is odd or even

Here is a basic concept:

```
var arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6];
var results = [];
for (var ii = 0, nn = arr.length; ii < nn; ii++)
{
   if (ii % 2 == 0) //0 % 2 = 0; 1 % 2 = 1; 2 % 2 = 0; 3 % 2 = 1;
   {
      //Even iteration: push a new array with the current value into results array
      results.push([arr[ii]]);
   }
   else
   {
      //Odd iteration: push current value into the last new array in results array
      results[results.length - 1].push(arr[ii]);
   }
}

//in the end, results array should look like: [[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]]
```

In your case, you'll need to keep an iteration count outside your filter anonymous function.

I edited your code and added a new `results` array:

```
var express = require('express');
var request = require('request');
var cheerio = require('cheerio');
var app     = express();

var url = 'http://testurl.com;
var name, email, status;

app.get('/scrape', function(req, res) {

    request(url, function (error, response, html) {

        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {

            var $ = cheerio.load(html);

            var results = []; //store final results here

            var data = {"name": name, "email": email, "status": status };

            var ii = 0;

            $('.scrape-class').filter(function() {

                var that = $(this);

                name = that.find('h5').text();
                email = that.find('.email').text(); 
                status = that.find('dl').children().first().text();

                data.name = name;
                data.email = email;
                data.status = status;

                console.log(data);

                if (ii % 2 == 0) { //0 % 2 = 0; 1 % 2 = 1; 2 % 2 = 0; 3 % 2 = 1;
                    //runs on iterations: 0, 2, 4, etc
                    results.push({"pair-number": results.length + 1, "pair": [data]});
                } else {
                    //runs on iterations: 1, 3, 5, etc
                    results[results.length - 1]["pair"].push(data);
                }

                ii++;
            });

            console.log(results); //print collected data after crawl
        }
    });
});

app.listen(80, function () {
    console.log('Example app listening on port 80!')
})
```